# INK Responsive Images

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, zurb-ink

**Column header images**

Trying to set up an INK email for 12 column followed by two six columns.

12 columns = 580px

Six columns 280px each - rest is padding
When I set a header image to 280px - the responsive version is too small as the column then becomes 320 and the img needs to be 300

"To use high resolution images, put height and width HTML attributes on the  tag, corresponding to the scaled size of the image in a desktop view (the width of its .columns container)." THIS DOES NOT WORK, the image goes way out of its container even in desktop view.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Provide your code please

Comment: <table class="row callout">
                  <tr>
                       <td class="wrapper">
                          <table class="six columns">
                           <tr>
                             <td>
                                <img width="282" height="169" src="http://www.---.co.uk/responsive/ink/column-400.jpg">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                           </table>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
</table>                

Working on mobile now but doesnt conform to the column width in Gmail..